# Лексические нормы

Tags: лексика

Почему сочетание "выразить признание за помощь" является ошибочным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражают признательность, а признания добиваются. Таковы грамматические нормы.

Comment: О, а я и не заметил. Спасибо!